# Unable to run jar file, getting error as Could not find or load main class (Maven Project)

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have created a Maven project, my class file located under src/test/java.
I am able to create the Jar file, when I build the project. But while running the jar file using command `java -jar Connet.jar`, getting error as:

> Error: Could not find or load main class.

POM:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>src/test/resources/ConnectUtility.LoginConnect</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>

                <finalName>Connet</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCRDy.png)

[POM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHkxl.png)

Comment: main class should have fully qualified name with all packages and not folders.
It should looks like this: `aaa.bbb.ccc.YourMainClass`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @Ivan i have chaned based on you comment but no luck...

Comment: Have you then checked what exactly was assembled into your jar and how exactly generated MANIFEST.MF file looks?

Answer (score 0):

First your class file should be located under source folder ( basically set on **src/main/java** path ).

Supposing your class content is the following:

**NOTE**: You should declare on it the main method as follow

```
package com.myproject;

public class MyProjectMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //initialization
    }

    //other methods
}
```

You can then configure your pom as follow:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>com.myproject.MyProjectMain</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
        <finalName>Connet</finalName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: i have update based on the comment above but no luck.

Comment: Can you share the relative path on your project of the class that contains main method after your updates based on my comment?

Comment: attached the screenshot for project and POM, for your reference

Comment: I took a look at your screenshot. As I said on my question your class should be on **src/main/java** while on your screenshot I see it is on **src/test/java**. Move the class under that path and retry. About the configuration of maven plugin instead, it seems good.

Comment: thanks for the update, i have moved it to src/main/java , but getting different error as "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver"

Comment: Ok, great! This latter is another kind of issue with selenium dependency. I think you need another question giving related details